# NDSolve Error control of an ODEs system

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

Having studied the answers to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88811/error-control-for-ndsolve) on how to control the error of `NDSolve`, I then tried to apply it to the following system of second-order nonlinear ODEs:

```
lowsol = With[{μ = 1/3}, 
NDSolve[{x''[t] == -Surd[x[t]^(Numerator@μ), Denominator@μ] + 
   Surd[(y[t] - x[t])^(Numerator@μ), Denominator@μ],
   y''[t] == -Surd[(y[t] - x[t])^(Numerator@μ), Denominator@μ], 
   y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == Sqrt[2 - y'[0]^2 - ((Surd[(x[0])^(Numerator@(μ + 1)), 
   Denominator@(μ + 1)]) + (Surd[(y[0] - x[0])^(Numerator@(μ + 1)), 
   Denominator@(μ + 1)]))/(μ + 1)]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", WorkingPrecision -> 61, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All, MaxSteps -> 2*^6, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1*^-8, MaxStepSize -> 1*^-4]] // Timing
```

which returns a pair of `Interpolating Function`. The system has a first integral of motion, which is set by its energy $E$, given by:
\begin{equation}
E=\frac{x'^2+y'^2}{2}+V(x,y)
\end{equation}

I then tried to plot this energy and see if it remains a constant in the following way:

```
With[{μ = 1/3}, 
Plot[{(((x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2)/2 + (3/4)*((x[t])^(4/3) + 
(y[t] - x[t])^(4/3)))} /. lowsol // RealExponent // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> All]]
```

but what was returned, is the following error:

```
ReplaceAll::rmix: Elements of {513.969,
{{x->InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000}},{5,1,7,{327114},
{4},{InterpolatingFunction[<<5>>]},0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},
{{0,5.086860500065041295097264042754353058189185580664200997582414*10^-
20,<<47>>,5.890559344799673487983779799641879661003747176870946110552147*10^-
15,<<327064>>}},
{{0,1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176680},<<49>>,
<<327064>>},{{{<<327115>>},
{<<327115>>}}}],y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0,10.00000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000}},<<3>>,{{{<<327115>>},{<<327115>>}}}]}}} are a 
mixture of lists and nonlists.
```

which states that there are elements which are a mixture of lists and nonlists. I would like to ask the following:

- Why did this error occur and how can I avoid it?
- How is it possible to reduce the computation time? In the question linked above, the computation time is significantly less than the one I need to acquire the results for my system.
- Is it possible to do the same for a number of initial conditions? I tried `ParametricNDSolve` but the plotting issue would remain.

**Update**

After running the piece of code provided by @zhk, I found out that the numerical integration returns a huge error estimate for `t=10^4` time units as it can be seen below:
[image]

How can I reduce this error?

Comment: You're setting `lowsol` equal to the result of `Timing`.  You probably want to set it equal to the result of `NDSolve`.  Try moving it inside the `With`: `With[{..}, lowsol = NDSolve[..]] // Timing`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I will try it now and let you know.

Comment: It seems like you should be using the Projection or SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta methods for NDSolve, which explicitly check that the invariant is conserved during the integration process. But I'm not getting that to work either.

Comment: @KraZug I read about those methods on the documentation but I was not able to make it run, though I have not idea why.

Comment: I integrate it with SPRK, but the invariant is not conserved: `\[Mu] = 1/3;
ode1 = x''[t] == -x[t]^\[Mu] + (-x[t] + y[t])^\[Mu];
ode2 = y''[t] == -(-x[t] + y[t])^\[Mu];
ics = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == Sqrt[2]};
invariant = (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2)/
    2 + (3/4)*(x[t]^(4/3) + (y[t] - x[t])^(4/3));
projerksol = 
  NDSolve[Flatten[{ode1, ode2, ics}], {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "PositionVariables" -> {x, y}}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 0.001][[1]];
Plot[Im[invariant /. projerksol], {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Can you explain how you get the invariant?

Comment: @KraZug The kinetic energy is always $ \sum (x_i^2+y_^2)$ while for the potential I just used the existence of a gradient: $F=-\nabla V$, where $V=V(x,y)$ is a scalar function.

Comment: @KraZug It does conserve for the first `t=10^3` time steps with only `10^-5` relative error but then it goes out of hand. Long time numerical integration seems to pose a problem

Comment: Note that there is an imaginary part that grows (the plot command that I included).

Comment: @KraZug Why would that play a role? I am using `Surd` to acquire only the corresponding real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
μ = 1/3;

ode1 = x''[t] == -x[t]^μ + (-x[t] + y[t])^μ;

ode2 = y''[t] == -(-x[t] + y[t])^μ;

lowsol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == Sqrt[2 - (x[0]^(1 + μ) + (-x[0] + y[0])^(1 + μ))/(1 + μ) - 
   y'[0]^2]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];

xy = Flatten /@Table[{t, Re[{(((x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2)/
      2 + (3/4)*((x[t])^(4/3) + (y[t] - x[t])^(4/3)))} /. First@lowsol]}, {t, 0, 10, 0.1}];

ListLinePlot[xy, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. Perhaps `Flatten` was what I was looking for? But why `"ExplicitEuler"`? Also, from the plot I can see an error estimate of `10^-3` for the first `10` time steps. I would like to bound it under `10^-4` since I am running `10^4` time steps integration. How can I apply the options: `WorkingPrecision -> 61, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All, MaxSteps -> 2*^6, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1*^-8, MaxStepSize -> 1*^-4` as above?