# How to increase NDSolve accuracy for 2nd order ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, precision-and-accuracy

My attempt to NDSolve a 2nd order nonlinear ODE

```
    rmin = 10^(-40); (* as close to 0 as possible*)

    bc = {u'[rmin] == 0, u'[1] == -u[1]}; 

    ode = r*u''[r] + 2*u'[r] + r*(Pi/64)*Exp[-128*r^2]*(1 - u[r]^5) == 0;


     s = NDSolve[{ode, bc}, u, {r, rmin, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 70, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 20];
```

resulted in an accuracy of about $10^{-12}$ as can be seen from the plot

```
Plot[ode[[1]] /. s, {r, rmin, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

An alternative approach ( from this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88811/error-control-for-ndsolve))

```
ClearAll[s, u, v, rmin]

rmin = 10^(-40);

defv = u'[r] == v[r];

odev = r*v'[r] + 2 v[r] + r*(Pi/64)*Exp[-128*r^2]*(1 - u[r]^5) == 0;

bcv = {v[rmin] == 0, u[1] == -v[1]};

AbsoluteTiming[
 s = NDSolve[{defv, odev, bcv}, {u, v}, {r, rmin, 1}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 1*^-8, MaxStepSize -> 1*^-4, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 33, AccuracyGoal -> 33, WorkingPrecision -> 70, 
    MaxSteps -> 2*^5, InterpolationOrder -> All];]
```

resulted in an increased  accuracy $10^{-19}$

```
Plot[odev[[1]] /. s, {r, rmin, 1}, PlotRange -> All
```

[image]

However computation time also increased significantly (about 1 min).

Is this the best accuracy Mathematica can achieve?

***Motivation:***   The above boundary value problem corresponds to the construction of initial data for General Relativity free evolution (see [Okawa, Cardoso, Pani, Phys.Rev.D, 90, 104032 (2014)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0533.pdf), eq.23 ).

[Here is an attempt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/205035/how-to-resolve-this-ndsolvefemcnsd-error) to address the [full problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0533.pdf).

This kind of evolution  ivolves only PDE's with respect to time and can in princple be performed in Mathematica.

However Mathematica probably lacks some tips and tricks used by Numerical GR algorithms in which case it will be more prone to crash due to numerical error on the initial data surface.

Comment: It's always good to add a sentence on what outcome you expect.

Comment: You might consider changing the `Method` used for integrating your ODE; I've found that for really stringent precision requirements, `Method -> 'StiffnessSwitching"` (which uses Bulirsch-Stoer) does remarkably well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use asymptotics at the initial value `r == 0` to define `u''[0]` for `ode2`:

```
ode = r*u''[r] + 2*u'[r] + r*(Pi/64)*Exp[-128*r^2]*(1 - u[r]^5) == 0;
ode2 = u''[r] == Piecewise[{
    {u''[r] /. First@Solve[ode, u''[r]], r != 0}
    },
   2 Coefficient[
     AsymptoticDSolveValue[{1/64 E^(-128 r^2) \[Pi] r (1 - u[r]^5) + 
         2 u'[r] + r u''[r] == 0, u'[0] == 0, u[0] == u0}, 
      u[r], {r, 0, 2}], r^2]
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[r, u, u0];

(*
 * SHOOTING METHOD - Find initial conditions for BVP
 *)
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode2, u'[0] == 0, u[0] == u0}, 
   u, {r, 0, 1}, {u0}, WorkingPrecision -> 32];
bvpic = FindRoot[psol[u0][1] + psol[u0]'[1],
 {u0, 0.00019`111, 0.0002`111}, (* prec = 111 so I can be lazy when changing WP *)
 WorkingPrecision -> 32, Method -> "Brent"]
(*
 * BVP SOLUTION
 *)
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode2, u'[0] == 0, u[0] == u0} /. bvpic,
   u, {r, 0, 1},
   WorkingPrecision -> 32, InterpolationOrder -> All];
sol[1] + sol'[1]
(* omitted some underflow/overflow errors that don't seem to matter
  {u0 -> 0.00019174759848606314091019577338064}
  0.*10^-37
*)
```

Solution:

```
ListLinePlot@sol
```

[image]

Interpolating error as measured by the differential equation (high points):

```
Plot[ode2 /. Equal -> Subtract /. u -> sol // RealExponent, {r, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
```

[image]

The step errors as measured by `ode2` should be zero plus rounding error, since that is how step methods work.  They can be seen in the low points of the above graph.  A common way to estimate the accuracy of a method is to run it at two different working precisions and measure the difference.  If we rerun the above at `MachinePrecision` to produce a solutions `solMP` and at `WorkingPrecision -> 40` to produce `sol40`, we get the following evidence of convergence:

```
Plot[{solMP[r] - sol[r], sol[r] - sol40[r]} // RealExponent,
 {r, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> 40]
```

[image]

So `solMP` has an accuracy better than `10^-8`,
and `sol` has an accuracy better than `10^-16`.