# Can Mathematica provide a reliable estimate of the numerical error from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

In the [Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html#15177) section of the *Mathematica* documentation for `PrecisionGoal`, one is told that

> Even though you may specify `PrecisionGoal -> n`, the results you get **may sometimes** have much less than n‐digit precision.

and that

> With `PrecisionGoal -> p` and `AccuracyGoal -> a`, the Wolfram Language **attempts** to make the numerical error in a result of size $x$ be less than $10^{-a}+10^{-p} \left| x\right|$.

According to these, after setting, for example, `WorkingPrecision -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 23, AccuracyGoal -> 50`, then `NDSolve` may give an output with a precision of, say, $19$ significant digits.

How can one fix this? If not, how can one be aware of the fact that *Mathematica* output is less precise than `WorkingPrecision -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 23, AccuracyGoal -> 50`? Can *Mathematica* be induced to give some estimate of the resulting numerical error?

Comment: You can calculate the error by substituting a numerical solution in the equation on the grid.

Comment: @Alex, that only works if the resulting interpolating function has high enough order for the PDE at hand. A better way to do this is to use manufactured solutions.

Comment: @user21 OK! Why not? Use what you need. In any case, to determine the error, you need to use the equation and solution. Or are there other options?:)

Comment: @AlexTrounev, if you want I can send you a detailed explanation I have that will be published in V12.1. ruebenkoATwolfram.com. If not I can post a link here after 12.1 is released.

Comment: @AlexTrounev There's some discussion of it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207373/4999) in an answer to another of the OP's questions.

Comment: For a 1D problem, there is also the option of integrating backwards, using the result of your first `NDSolve[]` to get initial conditions, and comparing the two solutions obtained.

Comment: @jheidk51 If we go back to the original problem on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/205035/can-ndsolve-address-spherical-gravitational-collapse , we will see that the main source of errors is not in the initial data, but in the system of nonlinear equations that describe the process of gravitational collapse.  Here in the answers there is not a single example with a nonlinear equation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can adapt the [MonitorMethod](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html#41467666):

```
Options[MonitorMethod] = {Method -> Automatic, 
   "MonitorFunction" -> 
    Function[{h, state, meth}, 
     Print[{"H" -> h, "SD" -> state@"SolutionData"}]]};
MonitorMethod /: 
  NDSolve`InitializeMethod[MonitorMethod, stepmode_, sd_, rhs_, 
   state_, OptionsPattern[MonitorMethod]] := Module[{submethod, mf},
   mf = OptionValue["MonitorFunction"];
   submethod = OptionValue[Method];
   submethod = 
    NDSolve`InitializeSubmethod[MonitorMethod, submethod, stepmode, 
     sd, rhs, state];
   MonitorMethod[submethod, mf]];
MonitorMethod[submethod_, mf_]["Step"[f_, h_, sd_, state_]] :=
  Module[{res},
   res = NDSolve`InvokeMethod[submethod, f, h, sd, state];
   If[Head[res] === NDSolve`InvokeMethod,
    Return[$Failed]]; (* submethod not valid for monitoring *)
   mf[h, state, submethod];
   If[SameQ[res[[-1]], submethod], res[[-1]] = Null, 
    res[[-1]] = MonitorMethod[res[[-1]], mf]];
   res];
MonitorMethod[___]["StepInput"] = {"Function"[All], "H", 
   "SolutionData", "StateData"};
MonitorMethod[___]["StepOutput"] = {"H", "SD", "MethodObject"};
MonitorMethod[submethod_, ___][prop_] := submethod[prop];
```

If the `Method` implements the `"StepError"` method, it will return the (scaled) step error estimate. (The only way to know the true error is to know the true solution and compare.)  By "scaled," *Mathematica* means
$$\text{scaled error}
 = {|\text{error}| \over 10^{-\text{ag}} + 10^{-\text{pg}} | x |} \,,$$
which will be between `0` and `1` when the $\text{error}$ satisfies the `AccuracyGoal` $\text{ag}$ and the `PrecisionGoal` $\text{pg}$.

The `MonitorMethod` takes a `"MonitorFunction"` option, which should be a function of the form

```
Function[{h, state, meth}, <...body...>]
```

where `h` is the step size, `state` is the [`` NDSolve`StateData ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) object, and `meth` is the `Method` object of the submethod.

Example use:

```
{sol, {errdata}} = Reap[
   NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, 
    x, {t, 0, 2}, 
    Method -> {MonitorMethod, 
      "MonitorFunction" -> 
       Function[{h, state, meth}, 
        Sow[meth@"StepError", "ScaledStepError"]]}, 
    MaxStepFraction -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 23, AccuracyGoal -> 50],
   "ScaledStepError"];

GraphicsRow[{
  ListLinePlot[Transpose@{Flatten@Rest@sol@"Grid", errdata},
   Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
   PlotLabel -> "Scaled error estimate"],
  Show[
   Plot[Sin[t] + Cos[t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red],
   ListLinePlot[sol, Mesh -> All],
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
   PlotLabel -> "Steps on top of exact solution"]
  }]
```

[image]

In our example, we know the exact solution, so we can check the actual error:

```
Block[{t = Flatten@sol@"Grid", data},
 data = Transpose@{t, (Sin[t] + Cos[t] - sol[t])/(
    10^-50 + 10^-23 Abs[Sin[t] + Cos[t]])};
 ListLinePlot[data,
  Epilog -> {PointSize@Medium, Tooltip[Point[#], N@Last@#] & /@ data},
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Actual scaled error"]
 ]
```

[image]

Of course, when I'm this interested in the error, it's usually because I have reasons for wondering whether the error estimates, which are based on discrete approximations to a function assumed to have a certain smoothness, are unreliable.

Comment: (+1), funny just a few days we internally talked about this and that it's not well known and now it pops up. Great answer.

Comment: @user21 Thanks.  Of course, I've rooted around `NDSolve` more than the average user. I noticed that `MonitorMethod` does not work with the submethods LSODA and Adams (maybe others?).  Aside from wondering why, I thought it would be nice if the restrictions were documented.

Comment: It absolutely should be documented or the restrictions removed, unfortunately sw spreads us out too thinly over the bread to keep on top of all these... I'll file it as a bug/suggestion but don't hold your breath! Sorry about that.

Comment: I filed it. We will see....

Comment: @user21 Thank you very much.  Kind of too bad about the LSODA restriction, since, being the usual `Automatic` method, it is the method one would most often want to monitor.

Answer (score 11):

I'll add more details when I have my copy of Wagon's "Mathematica in Action" again, but as I mentioned in a comment, one possible way to check your solution would be to "integrate backwards", with initial conditions taken from your first call to `NDSolve[]`. Using Michael's example:

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 2},
                    AccuracyGoal -> 50, MaxStepFraction -> 1,
                    PrecisionGoal -> 23, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
```

Here's the "backwards" version:

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[2] == sol1[2], x'[2] == sol1'[2]}, x, {t, 2, 0},
                    AccuracyGoal -> 50, MaxStepFraction -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 23,
                    WorkingPrecision -> 95];
```

(note that I had to shrink the `WorkingPrecision` slightly)

Plot them together:

```
Plot[sol1[t] - sol2[t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 60]
```

[image: plot of difference]

and we see that there is a discrepancy of at most $2.5\times 10^{-15}$.

---

Another possibility is to leverage `ParametricNDSolve[]` to see what happens if the initial conditions are perturbed. Adapting one of the examples from the docs to Michael's example:

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1 + h, x'[0] == 1 + h}, x,
                             {t, 0, 2}, {h}, AccuracyGoal -> 50, MaxStepFraction -> 1,
                            PrecisionGoal -> 23, WorkingPrecision -> 100];

With[{h = 1*^-6}, 
     Plot[Evaluate[pf[0][t] + {-h, 0, h} pf'[0][t]], {t, 0, 5}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Gray, {ColorData[97, 1]}, Gray}, 
          Filling -> {1 -> {3}}, WorkingPrecision -> 60]]
```

[image: perturbation of initial conditions]

A very sensitive ODE would display a much wider band.

Comment: (I'll prolly edit this answer later to put in a more interesting example, like Duffing's equation.)